# Quadratic equation of graphs

Tags: roots, quadratics

How can I express $p$ and $h$ in terms of $k$? I'm thinking of $0=-(k-p)^{2} + h$. However, there are $2$ variables in this equation, how can I get rid of one of them?[image]

Comment: Hint: $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)=d$. Equate that and see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $f(x)=-(x)(x-k)=-x^2+kx$ because $0$ and $k$ are roots of $f$ and compare with $f(x)=-(x-p)^2+h=-x^2+2px-p^2+h$. That will give you

$$2p=k \Rightarrow p=k/2$$
$$-p^2+h=0 \Rightarrow h=p^2=k^2/4$$

Comment: I can't understand -(x)(x-k), could you please explain it more? Thxx

Comment: If a quadratic function has roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ then you can write $f(x)=a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$. That's what I did. Your function has roots $0$ and $k$ (because the graph cut axi $x$ at those points) so we can write $f(x)=a(x-0)(x-k)$ and $a=-1$.

Comment: Ohh I finally understand this thank you so much

Comment: You are very welcome.